anyone command line keyword blocking programmings pls?
Still trying to block all online gambling.
Pluckeye is good for this but not fool proof.
anymore programs or extensions that allow a command line block?
a backup would solve it pls?

sorry meant to put anymore. autocorrect.

FYI you can [edit] your question (including the title) if you make a typo
